# How to format list data and write to csv file in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, csv

I'm getting data from a website and storing them inside a list of variables. Now I need to send these data to a CSV file.
The website data is printed and shown below.

**The data getting from the Website**

```
['Company Name: PATRY PLC', 'Contact Name: Jony Deff', 'Company ID: 234567', 'CS ID: 236789', 'MI/MC:', 'Road Code:']
['Mailing Address:', 'Street: 19700 I-45 Spring, TX 77373', 'City: SPRING', 'State: TX', 'Postal Code: 77388', 'Country: US']
['Physical Address:', 'Street: 1500-1798 Runyan Ave Houston, TX 77039, USA', 'City: HOUSTON', 'State: TX', 'Postal Code: 77039', 'Country: US']
['Registration Period', 'Registration Date/Time', 'Registration ID', 'Status']
['2020-2025', 'MAY-10-2020  15:54:12', '26787856889l', 'Active']
```

I'm using for loop to get these data using the below code:

```
listdata6 = []
for c6 in cells6:
    listdata6.append(c6.text)
```

Now I have all data inside the 5 list variables. How can I write these data into CSV file like the below format?
[image]

Comment: Please share the url?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to have two header rows.
But I'm afraid your CSV interpreter (which seem to be MS Excel) won't be able to merge cells like you show on the screenshot.

Based on the structure of your data (five lists where keys and values are mixed) looks like you probably have to construct both headers semi-manually.
Here is the code:

```
company_info = ['Company Name: PATRY PLC', 'Contact Name: Jony Deff', 'Company ID: 234567', 'CS ID: 236789', 'MI/MC:', 'Road Code:']
mailaddr_info = ['Mailing Address:', 'Street: 19700 I-45 Spring, TX 77373', 'City: SPRING', 'State: TX', 'Postal Code: 77388', 'Country: US']
physaddr_info = ['Physical Address:', 'Street: 1500-1798 Runyan Ave Houston, TX 77039, USA', 'City: HOUSTON', 'State: TX', 'Postal Code: 77039', 'Country: US']
reg_data = ['Registration Period', 'Registration Date/Time', 'Registration ID', 'Status']
status_data = ['2020-2025', 'MAY-10-2020  15:54:12', '26787856889l', 'Active']

# composing 1st header's row
header1 = ''.join(',' for i in range(len(company_info))) # add commas
header1 += mailaddr_info[0].strip(':') # adds 1st item which is header of that data
header1 += ''.join(',' for i in range(1, len(mailaddr_info)))
header1 += physaddr_info[0].strip(':') # adds 1st item which is header of that data
header1 += ''.join(',' for i in range(1, len(physaddr_info)))
header1 += ''.join(',' for i in range(len(reg_data))) # add commas

# composing 2nd header's row
header2 = ','.join( item.split(':')[0].strip(' ') for item in company_info) + ','
header2 += ','.join( item.split(':')[0].strip(' ') for item in mailaddr_info[1:]) + ','
header2 += ','.join( item.split(':')[0].strip(' ') for item in physaddr_info[1:]) + ','
header2 += ','.join( item.split(':')[0].strip(' ') for item in reg_data)

# finally, the data row. Note we replace comma with empty char because some items contain comma.
# You can further elaborate by encapsulating comma-containing items with quotes "" which
# is treated as text by CSV interpreters.
data_row = ','.join( item.split(':')[-1].strip(' ') for item in company_info)
data_row += ','.join( item.split(':')[-1].strip(' ').replace(',','') for item in mailaddr_info)
data_row += ','.join( item.split(':')[-1].strip(' ').replace(',','') for item in physaddr_info)+ ','
data_row += ','.join( item for item in status_data)

# writing the data to CSV file
with open("test_file.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(header1 + '\n')
    f.write(header2 + '\n')
    f.write(data_row + '\n')
```

If I import that file using MS Excel and set 'Comma' as separator in text import wizard you will get something like that:

[image: MS Excel screenshot after import]

You can wrap it into a helper class which takes these five lists and exposes `write_csv()` method to the outside world.

Comment: Appreciate your support. Is there any way to save these data into a CSV file in the proper way?

Comment: Please give me suggestions to save these data in any order than my one. I need to save that list of data to read it properly.

Comment: @Sidath is the original format the data from website comes JSON?

Comment: No. There are 5 tables and I scrape the data from the table and add to a list. `table2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='r1:1:pfl1']/table/tbody/tr/td/table")))
cells2 = table2.find_elements("xpath", ".//tbody//tr")

listdata2 = []
for cell in cells2:
    listdata2.append(cell.text)`